# What is the difference between EKS and EC2 installed kubernets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I'm newbie in AWS usage.
I don't understand the difference between EKS and EC2 installed kubernets?

> Amazon EKS makes it easy for you to run Kubernetes on AWS without needing to install and operate your own Kubernetes clusters.

Does this means that we could install Kubernets to EC2 and use EC2 instead of EKS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely could install Kubernetes to EC2 and setup the configuration yourself.  However, EKS will handle the bulk of the setup, configuration, maintenance, and monitoring for you.  Check out the [feature](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/features/) page to determine if it is worth it to you.